# Java - Building communicator what includes video/sound/picture/msg

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, audio, video

i've little problem with conception how to implement this project , cause i don't know how to send to client/server in one moment video/sound/msg , how to filtrate this stream  ? If someone have any idea how to solve this problem i would be thankful. Thanks anyway.

Comment: multithread severer to handle few clients , i had done all of operations to capture camera , mic sound . I have moduls to send each of them separately , but not together . To send msg i need to end sending frames or captured bytes by mic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create TX which transmits UDP stream to RX. You will have to implement UDP packet loss recovery yourself, because UDP is connection less, unreliable protocol. I suggest UDP because you will get flexibility on creating flow/error control mechanisms yourself. While you can do same with TCP, but it adds latency, and user will see pauses in video play. So better to go with UDP, bit freezing is better than pause.

Comment: I thought that rxtx is for serial ports , so i should look for any turtorials , but will it help me to manipulate stream ? Should i insert some instruction between packet from camera or mic ?

Comment: @KacperSobisz TXRX is not just for serial ports, TX= transmitter (Sender), RX = Receiver (server).

Comment: If you could answer me on one more question , should i insert some instruction into packets to check is it camera or voice ? Or you have another idea ?

Comment: @KacperSobisz look for RTSP, may be better than UDP. And you can use xuggler API for processing audio video. It is nice API, and you will get ready made examples in internet.